# Tkinter GUI - Tk & Toplevel

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit, toplevel

I've been unable to successfully launch separate windows - the main window Tk, naturally, has to be the initiator of .mainloop, and originally, that was the only window in the GUI. After I completed the GUI, tested it's functionality, and was **slightly** proud of myself, I got all confident and decided to incorporate a user login window as well.

The program itself is just a question-and-answer quiz that randomizes a test on the 50 United State's Capital cities - an idea I'd **sort of** stolen from one of my Python PDF guides, however, I wrote the code independently, partly as an exercise and partly to learn hands-on for the experience. But after running into difficulties  trying to get the Toplevel window to actually **launch**, I couldn't manage to pull it off even with every resource and guide I **had** for Tkinter open at the same time!

Tried wait_window... tried grab_set() and focus_set() ... and again, I know the main window has to initiate the mainloop. What in the ****world**** am I doing wrong, here?! Is it the way I have my code structured altogether?! Bad structure? Anyway, here's the code... I hope this site formats code to consolidate after a certain number of lines because it's quite long.

All that code, so little skill... LOL. Thing needs some exception handling, too... I know that. Any advise, guidance, and/or assistance towards ****any**** aspect of my code is not only welcome, it's greatly appreciated, so please, if there's something beyond this two-window dilemma I can't seem to conquer, feel free to put it on front street! Thank you in advance! :)

## My Code

---

```py
    class MainWin(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.title('Minimal Code')
    
    class Login(tk.Toplevel):
        def __init__(self, master=MainWin()):
            super().__init__()
            self.name = tk.StringVar()
        enter code here
            userlbl = tk.Label('Enter Name: ')
            userent = tk.Entry(width=18, textvariable=self.name)
```

Ok, so for minimal coding to replicate the basic issue I'm having, please assume I've entered in the *.grid()* info for the label and entry widgets... ultimately, how I'd like this to work is for the login screen (Toplevel) to pop up - and if the Main window is behind it, that's no problem, just disable until the login window is closed - yet I can't, for the life of me, seem to accomplish this.

I really don't want to have to rewrite the entire thing, but I'm considering it... to see if using Canvas can more easily execute this particular action.

Comment: P.S. I just noticed I've since removed the __name__ = blah blah... as nothing I attempted in my two-window trouble seemed to work. I'll go back through the guides and resources I referenced to find those actual 'attempts' in their Python code state. Or... someone could just add code that will actually work for me? LOL

Comment: see answer (seems that you have spotted the same in part).

Comment: First `master=MainWin()` is not recommended.  Second `master` argument is not used in `super().__init__()` so the `master` argument is useless.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the classes is back to front.

so the `Main` fails because it is initialised befor it is called:

```
class Login(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=Main(), takefocus=True):
        super().__init__()
```

I switched the order around and this error goes.

1. first this: `class Main(tk.Tk):`
2. then this: `class Login(tk.Toplevel):`

I dont know if this makes the code work, but it removes the error.

Also, when you `instantiate` a class it needs the brackets, so

```
master=Main
```

becomes

```
master=Main()
```

Comment: Ok, but then where does the top level window come in? One of the resources in a PDF file or the internet (can't recall which) started the mainloop in a way I'd never seen done before... I probably have this wrong, but it was something similar to this:

```python

top = Toplevel()

main = Tk(top)

main.wait_window(top)

main.mainloop()

main.withdraw()
```

I tried as you said and put tk.Tk() first, and put the tk.Toplevel class below it... I'm still getting basically a 'NOT RESPONDING' type __blank__ window when I run it.

Comment: @TrexxæByte :  What I might suggest is creating a new post with the minimal necessary code. This will help users help you resolve each problem Here is a guide that will be helpful to you:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you feel as though creating an entire new post would be best, I will do so, but alternatively, as it's not exactly an issue affecting my livelihood or anything, I just edited my original question and cut the code down to the basic two windows... so now I just require the mainloop. Again, I haven't added it as this is basically the question I need answered. I have no idea how to launch these windows yet only have the Toplevel accessible. 

I've tried root = MainWin()
login = Login()
root.wait_window(login)

and a few variations of that. I've also tried to have Toplevel take focus.